# How do I find the high water mark (for sessions) on Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, session, oracle9i

How can I find the high water mark (the historical maximum number of concurrent users) in an **oracle database (9i)**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT sessions_highwater FROM v$license;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max_utilization from v$resource_limit where resource_name = 'sessions';
```

A good overview of Oracle system views can be found [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/dynamic_performance_views.html).